# how to execute a fast fourier transform in a loss function for neural network training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensor

I'm currently working on a fully convolutional neural network (image in, image out) and i'm trying to implement a loss function that does the fast fourier transform of the 2 images before doing some operation on them, the code is like this

```
def fourierLoss2(y_actual,y_pred):
  actual_fft = tf.signal.rfft3d(y_actual)
  pred_fft = tf.signal.rfft3d(y_pred)
  lossV=tf.math.real(tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(actual_fft-pred_fft)))
  return lossV

with strategy.scope():
  model = hd_unet_model(INPUT_SIZE)
  model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.1),
                loss= fourierLoss2,
                metrics=tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError())
```

the 2 tensors (y_actual,y_pred) have type float.
but if i try to train the model i get the following error

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py:585 _call_for_each_replica
        self._container_strategy(), fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py:96 call_for_each_replica
        return _call_for_each_replica(strategy, fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py:237 _call_for_each_replica
        coord.join(threads)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py:389 join
        six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py:703 reraise
        raise value
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py:297 stop_on_exception
        yield
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py:323 run
        self.main_result = self.main_fn(*self.main_args, **self.main_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:757 train_step
        self.trainable_variables)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:2722 _minimize
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py:1073 gradient
        unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/imperative_grad.py:77 imperative_grad
        compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py:151 _gradient_function
        grad_fn = ops._gradient_registry.lookup(op_name)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/registry.py:97 lookup
        "%s registry has no entry for: %s" % (self._name, name))

    LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: RFFT3D
```

After some research i understood that the problem is that the operation tf.signal.rfft3d does not have a registered gradient function.
Does anybody know a way to get around this problem?

Comment: I'm trying to find out why `tf.signal.rfft2d` does not work in my loss function. Where did you look to figure out that `tf.signal.rfft3d` does not have a registered gradient function?

Comment: sorry man but it was too much time ago and it's been more than 2 years since i finished this project, i'm no expert on this stuff so probably i just kept searching until i found the solution, maybe on tensorflow documentation or here on stack overflow, but cannot tell for sure.

Comment: No problem! Your solution below didn't work for me, I upgraded my TF and it fixed things. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a solution to the problem, instead of using `tf.signal.rfft3d` i had to use `tf.signal.fft3d`, this function has an entry for the gradient and works in a loss function, the downside is that now i had to convert the float tensors to complex type before the fourier trasform